# What is an example of spanning set with linearly independent vectors that is not a Hamel Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

While trying to distinguish the definitions of Hamel and Schauder bases of infinite dimensional vector spaces, I was told that the true definition of a Hamel basis is not "a spanning set with linearly independent vectors", but instead "a spanning set that guarantees unique representation of each vector in the space" (although both definitions coincide in the finite dimensional case).

The second definition seems stronger, so I seek an example, in the context of infinite dimensional vector spaces, of a Hamel basis by the first definition, but not by the second.

Comment: There is no difference, even in infinite dimension.

Comment: If you are worried about the meaning of words then perhaps you should be a bit more precise with the terms you use. "Spanning", for example, might have different meanings in topological vs. algebraic contexts.  So does "representation of vectors".

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc _Which_ notions are different? Yes of course the notion of Hamel basis is different from the notion of Schauder basis, as the OP more or less says. The question was about two definitions of "Hamel basis"; _those_ two notions are the same.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are correct. The proof is analogous to the proof in finite dimension. Linear independence of finite sets does not guarantee unique representation in Schauder bases (not Hamel bases). Examples of this can be found on this site. Thank you for the answers, I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You say the two definitions are equivalent in the finite-dimensional case. How do you prove that? If you don't know how to prove it you're just believing what you're told - if you do know how to prove it you should note that finite dimension doesn't come up...